# Issue with Modal present and dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` that has 20 points padding around the edge of the main content. This is clear colour to be transparent.

I then use the following to open it as a `Modal`.

`noteDetailController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
 present(noteDetailController, animated: false, completion: nil)`

My idea was that I would set a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to allow the user to tap anywhere in the padding area to dismiss the `Modal`.

The following is hit by this `UITapGestureRecognizer`, inside the `Modal ViewController`

`self.parentController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

I'm having issues where the `ViewController` underneath the `Modal` seems to be responding the pressing the screen and there's a major lag in loading and dismissing `Modals`.

Does this logic seem correct, am I doing things in a way that you would expect to work? It almost seems like the `present` and `dismiss` start happening out of sync and several `Modals` are loaded.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A suggestion would be to try adding the noteDetailController.view as a subView to the current controller with bounds equal to the the parentViewController's frame. Even though it's not a direct solution to your question, I see it as worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller underneath should not be getting touch events while another view controller is placed above it.

1. Make a segue to the modal controller as Kind: Present Modally, Presentation: Over Current Context, and call the segue as `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showModal", sender: nil)`
2. Make sure the view of the modal view controller has checked "User Interaction Enabled" and has a clear color background.
3. Connect the container view of the modal to the modal view controller with an IBOutlet, add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the modal's view (padding) and implement a UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method to detect that the tap was indeed only in padding and not in the container view itself:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hide(gr:)))
       tap.delegate = self
       view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   }

   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
       if let v = touch.view, v.isDescendant(of: containerView) {
           return false
       }
       return true
   }

   @objc func hide(gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       dismiss(animated: true)
   }
   ```